# Example of maximal multicurve complex

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, examples, mapping-class-groups

in this [paper](https://sci-hub.se/10.1515/crll.2000.028) we have :

" On the Teichmüller tower of mapping class groups By Allen Hatcher at Ithaca, Pierre Lochak at Paris and Leila Schneps."

Definition. The **maximal multicurve complex $H(\Sigma)$** is the two-dimensional cell complex having vertices the isotopy classes of maximal multicurves in $\Sigma$, with an edge joining two vertices whenever the corresponding maximal multicurves differ by a single S-move or A-move, and with faces added to fill in all cycles of the following five forms:...

**example :**[image]if $\Sigma$ has type $(0,4)$ or $(1,1)$, the two cases when a maximum multicurve contains just one circle, then $H(\Sigma)$ is the two-dimensional complex shown in figure 6 , consisting entirely of triangles since only the relations (3A) or (3S) are possible in these two cases. The vertices of $H(\Sigma)$ are labelled by slopes, which classify the nontrivial isotopy classes of circles on $\Sigma$. This is a familiar fact for the torus, where slopes are defined via homology. For the $(0,4)$ surface, slopes are defined by lifting curves to the torus via the standard two-sheeted branched covering of the sphere by
the torus, branched over four points which become the four boundary circles of the $(0,4)$
surface.

[image]

> i can't understand this example . why **maximal multicurve complex $H(\Sigma)$** for  type $(0,4)$ or $(1,1)$ is figure $6$ ? why vertices of $H(\Sigma)$ are labelled by slopes ? why we draw hyperbolic triangle in Poincaré disk ?

I think [this](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/apps/teich-nav/about.html) is help for me.also I think this is related to page 98 "farey complex "in
A Primer on Mapping Class Groups
Book by Benson Farb and Dan Margalit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this in [Y. N. MINSKY, “A geometric approach to the complex of curves on a surface](http://libgen.gs/get.php?md5=2bb9c9b2eccb74a5bbc19ead14836263&key=HIWMAJPWIHHXF1WT&doi=10.1142/9789814503921_0009)

and [automorphisms of the pants complex](http://www.math.utah.edu/vigre/pubs/pdfs/margalit_2004_apc.pdf)